# Akka.net load balancing and span out processing

Tags: akka, akka.net

I am looking to build a system that is able to process a stream of requests that needs a long processing time say 5 min each. My goal is to speed up request processing with minimal resource footprint which at times can be a burst of messages.

I can use something like a `service bus` to queue the request and have multiple process (a.k.a Actors in akka) that can subscribe for a message and start processing. Also can have a watchdog that looks at the queue length in the service bus and create more actors/ actor systems or stop a few.

if I want to do the same in the Actor system like `Akka.net` how can this be done. Say something like this:

- I may want to **spin up/stop** new Remote Actor systems based on my request  queue length
- Send the message to any one of the **available actor** who can start processing without having to check who has the bandwidth to process on the sender side.
- Messages should not be lost, and if the actor fails, it should be passed to next available actor.

can this be done with the Akka.net or this is not a valid use case for the actor system. Can some one please share some thoughts or point me to resources where I can get more details.

Comment: If you already have something like ServiceBus in front of your system, I don't see what advantage are you looking for. 

1. Akka.NET is a toolkit / library. It's meant to be used from within your process, but it won't spawn other machines on demand. You need resource manager for that. 2. & 3. can be solved by service bus itself.

Comment: @Horusiath: I would like to move out of Windows service bus 1.1 as soon as possible. its a pain to deploy as part of our solution especially when systems don't have access to internet. I see that there is something called `akka.clustering` Just digging to see if that can help here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I may want to spin up/stop new Remote Actor systems based on my request queue length

This is not supported out of the box by Akka.Cluster. You would have to build something custom for it.

However Akka .NET has [pool routers](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers#pools-vs-groups) which are able to resize automatically according to configurable parameters. You may be able to build something around them.

> Send the message to any one of the available actor who can start processing without having to check who has the bandwidth to process on the sender side.

If you look at [Akka .NET Routers](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers), there are various strategies that can be used to assign work. `SmallestMailbox` is probably the closest to what you're after.

> Messages should not be lost, and if the actor fails, it should be passed to next available actor.

Akka .NET supports At Least Once Delivery. Read more about it [in the docs](http://getakka.net/docs/persistence/at-least-once-delivery) or [at the Petabridge blog](https://petabridge.com/blog/akkadotnet-at-least-once-message-delivery/).

Comment: Thanks, BTW what do you think of a solution where the Routee did a perodic Ask instead of tell from the router. i.e. whenever the actor is free to take on more work, it can ask for any available job to process to the parent actor and continue working. is  this a usable pattern? and does it have a huge pitfall in any ways

Comment: Ask is typically discouraged because doing request/response has an impact on throughput. Ideally design in terms of push. Also, it should be the router that manages routees; there shouldn't really be an inverse relationship. If you're using a pool router then you won't even know exactly how many routees there are (it is managed automatically).

Comment: Thanks again, I did make some progress based on your comment but I don't see the pool actors grow based on load. I have asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205189/akka-net-why-are-my-pool-actors-not-scaling-up-or-down-based-on-load  for it, could you please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

While you may achieve some of your goals with Akka cluster, I wouldn't advise that. From your requirements it clearly states that your concerns are oriented about:

- Reliable message delivery (where service buses and message queues are better option). There are a lot of solutions here, depending on your needs i.e. MassTransit, NServiceBus or queues (RabbitMQ).
- Scaling workers (which is infrastructure problem and it's not solved by actor frameworks themselves). From what you've said, you don't even even need a cluster.

You could use akka for building a message processing logic, like workers. But as I said, you don't need it if your goal is to replace existing service bus.

Comment: I was looking at http://prochera.com/blog/2014/07/15/building-a-scalable-and-highly-available-reactive-applications-with-akka-load-balancing-revisited/ which kind of explains the same thing I am looking for, so curious why you think that Akka cannot be used for these kind of requirements

Comment: I'm not saying that Akka cannot be used for this requirement, I'm saying that using akka cluster is unnecessary complex, than for example having X not correlated actor systems pulling data from the same queue/service bus. Also article you linked doesn't mention using queues (only some abstract "external source"), which changes things a little.

Comment: While it's possible, it for sure brings a lot more work, than in case of other technologies like queues of service buses, which were build specifically for this.